# XML Layout, buttons under a listview/textview

Tags: java, android

I have an XML layout with an imageview and textview on the same row. This works perfectly but now i want to place three buttons underneath this and I cant figure out what layout to use to implemts these buttons as the layout just sets within the row between the image and textview.

The following image shows what Im trying to achieve. (b1,b2 and b3 represent the buttons)

[image: layout]

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction for how i can get this layout?

Heres my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLink"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/cons" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout now with misplaced textview/layout
[image: anotherlayout]

Comment: You could do a Relative Layout instead and utilize the layout_below and layout_toRightOf parameters as needed.

Comment: @user1352057 try with the posted solution that will set layout as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLink"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/cons" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="b1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="b2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="b3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That definetly gives me the layout I want but it has obscured my layout of the textview and the imageview. As shown in the first post edit

Comment: @user1352057 i edited my answer now your textview with text "Contacts" will be at center. I think you are concern with that If I am not wrong?

Comment: @Praik. Many thanks for you answer. I have managed to sort this myself through re-sizing the linearlayout.

Comment: @user1352057 that's great.

Comment: One last question, what is the correct layout i should be looking to use if i want to posistion the buttons further down the layout?

Comment: Linear layout will be good to position controls in sequence horizontal / vertical.